# Neo4j/Cypher create unique relationship in highly concurrent environment

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I need to have some kind of unique constraint for a given relationship type.

```
(a)-[:RELATION]->(b)
```

In order to achieve this I'm using `CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b)`

In the concurrent environment if multiple threads can create `(a)-[:RELATION]->(b)` between same nodes I'm getting `UniquePathNotUniqueException` and multiple relations created due to nature of neo4j transaction isolation.

I found the only way of creating unique relation at the moment is write lock both nodes.

Is there's other way to create guaranteed unique relationship?

**UPDATE**

That's the approach I used at the end

```
MATCH (a), (b) 
SET a._lock_ = true, b._lock_ = true 
MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b) 
REMOVE a._lock_, b._lock_
```

with additional retry loop with exponential backoff process possible deadlocks.

Comment: Did you try `MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b)`? I think that should handle write locks implicitly.

Comment: merge doesn't guarantee uniqueness

Comment: Do `a` and `b` already exist in the graph and you're `MATCH`ing on them? If so then I'm pretty sure `MERGE` will grab a write lock on them in this case.

Comment: both nodes already exist. `MERGE` doesn't take write locks and relationship uniqueness not guaranteed. try run some tests.

Comment: I wasn't exactly correct. When we're creating relationship `MERGE` will grab locks on both nodes, but because we're not locking nodes when matching duplicate relationship might be created when query executed concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the approach I used at the end

```
MATCH (a), (b) 
SET a._lock_ = true, b._lock_ = true 
MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b) 
REMOVE a._lock_, b._lock_
```

with additional retry loop with exponential backoff to process possible deadlocks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `MERGE` on the relationship but beforehand you need to grab locks to prevent concurrency issues. This is most easy done as a side effect from removing a non existing property:

```
MATCH (a:Label{key:value}), (b:Label{key:value2})
REMOVE a._non_existing_property, b._non_existing_property
MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b)
```

### Update

My statement above has the danger of deadlocks (which will be detected and handled gracefully by Neo4j). To prevent that the lock(s) must be taken in consistent order, e.g. by smaller node id:

```
MATCH (a:Label{key:value}), (b:Label{key:value2})
WITH a, b, case when id(a) < id(b) then a else b end as locknode
REMOVE locknode._non_existing_property
MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b)
```

Comment: In my case remove non-existent property doesn't work. but setting and removing property on nodes does. `MATCH (a), (b) SET a._lock_ = true, b._lock_ = true MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b) REMOVE a._lock_, b._lock_`